# Camera With Aspect Ratio and Captured Image in Same Aspect Ratio In Flutter

Tags: flutter, camera, aspect-ratio

I want camera with aspect ratio selection and preview size will be same as aspect ratio selected by user.

I have tried with some plugins which is working fine in iPhone and Android but not working as per expectation in iPad.

I have tried with below both plugins and changes multiple code snippet to get around with client's requirement

1. https://pub.dev/packages/camera
2. https://pub.dev/packages/camerawesome

Still its not enough to fulfils my requirement as mentioned.

So if anyone has implemented this type of functionality then please share with community